# convert a table to a longtable to span across multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable

I generated a table with a generator but it doesn't fit one page, so i would like it to span across multiple pages. i read that only the longtable is able to split across pages, so i tried to convert it but i didn't managed to. How can i convert this table to a longtable?
this is the table code

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.4cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{7.8cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.2cm}|} 
\hline
Ruolo    & Luogo del problema (pagina) & Descrizione del problema                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & Euristiche violate                   & Gravità  \\ 
\hline
Studente & Amministr. del corso        & lo studente in options, altro, metodi di iscrizione, può vedere quanti utenti si sono iscritti e in quale modo.                                                                                                                                                                & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Amministr. del corso        & lo studente in options, altro, iscrizioni, può vedere l'elenco dei partecipanti al corso, ma iscrizioni è fuorviante perchè sembra indicare che lo studente può iscrivere altre persone                                                                                        & Convivialità                         & 1        \\ 
\hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione della reportistica sono presenti un numero eccessivo di voci e di pagine possibili e non è chiara la differenza fra ogni singola pagina; quando vi si accede non ci sono indicazioni di come interagire, né sono presenti dati                                   & Navigazione, Stile                   & 3        \\ 
\hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & la visualizzazione dei filtri è confusa e non si sa quali dati ci si può aspettare di trovare; i filtri sono mal organizzati                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione di overview statistics non è presente ne la legenda per leggere i grafici ne l'indicazione dei dati su ascisse e ordinate; non si può interagire con i grafici                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & spesso i filtri sono graficamente diversi fra le diverse pagine della reportistica                                                                                                                                                                                             & Coerenza, Stile                      & 2        \\ 
\hline
admin    & Amministr. sito             & la reportistica è scritta in modo troppo tecnico e risulta incomprensibile per l'utente (es.:"The user with id '2' viewed the course with id '89'.")                                                                                                                           & Convivialità                         & 3        \\ 
\hline
admin    & Amministr. sito             & in un corso, l'elenco degli studenti ha un filtro con 54 tasti, il funzionamento di questo filtro è controintuitivo                                                                                                                                                            & Chiarezza o affordance, Flessibilità & 2        \\ 
\hline
Admin    & Calendario                  & Le CTA non sono visibili a causa del contrasto con il colore dello sfondo                                                                                                                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Categorie                   & Le dimensioni dei quadrati/rettangoli presentanti i corsi hanno forme e disposizioni differenti senza un apparente motivo                                                                                                                                                      & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & cliccando su page settings appare soltanto l'opzione "quadri delle competenze", non si capisce a cosa faccia riferimento questa funzione                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & le Categorie non aiutano ad orientarsi all'interno di whoteach, sono poco significative (es. il corso di digitalizzazione 4.0 è dentro alla categoria sviluppo personale mentre potrebbe tranquillamente rientrare nella categoria abilità informatiche)                       & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & Premendo sulla voce menù "categorie" la schermata rimane quasi uguale alla home, non si capisce se l'operazione richiesta è andata a buon fine                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & pur senza aver fatto login, è possibile navigare le Categorie e vedere chi sono le aziende clienti di whoteach                                                                                                                                                                 & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & in una categoria, le cards delle sottocategorie e dei corsi sono troppo simili e non separati in modo chiaro                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & l'informazione sulla data di quando una categoria è stata modificata l'ultima volta non è significativa                                                                                                                                                                        & Visibilità                           & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Categorie                   & come studente è possibile vedere corsi a cui non posso accedere, ne posso fare richiesta di accedere                                                                                                                                                                           & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\hline
Admin    & Gestione corsi              & la riordinazione dei corsi èoco comprensibile, buono l'uso delle icone, ma non chiaro lo scopo per il quale è necessario selezionare le voci                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Home                        & in home (pagina delle Categorie) non c'è un modo semplice per cercare un corso, bisogna navigare all'interno di ogni categoria; si riesce ad accedere facilmente ad un corso solo se si ha il link                                                                             & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Menù navigazione            & a differenza degli altri "pallini" del menu, che aprono un submenu a fumetto, l'icona dei messaggi apre una sidebar a cassetto                                                                                                                                                 & Coerenza                             & 2        \\ 
\hline
Docente  & Preferenze                  & Icona dell'occhio per scurire lo sfondo visibile e disponibile solo in alcune pagine non in tutte                                                                                                                                                                              & Familiarità                          & 1        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & riguarda alla timeline sui dati non è ben comprensibile la sua funzione, probabilmente una scelta stilistica, ma non ne sono sicuro (io la associo ad altre funzioni)                                                                                                          & Familiarità                          & 3        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & Non capisco il senso di permettere ad uno studente di poter modificare il layout della pagina profilo                                                                                                                                                                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & Per un profilo studente, nella pagina del profilo ci sono informazioni inutili (privacy e politiche, sessioni, primo e ultimo accesso al sito, possibilità di accedere ad app tramite qr code senza che esista l'app)                                                          & Familiarità, Chiarezza o affordance  & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina dle profilo i colori delle bulletlist sono diversi fra di loro (gialli e rossi) senza che ci sia una spiegazione del perchè                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina del profilo non è chiaro cosa il tasto modifica permetta di modificare, perchè sembra che sia per i campi sotto ma se si preme se ne possono modificare anche altri                                                                                               & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & la voce profilo moodlenet nei dettagli del profilo non è spiegato cosa sia, non si sa dove reperire informazioni, non è utile per lo studente standard                                                                                                                         & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 2        \\ 
\hline
Studente & Profilo                     & Non è possibile spostare il "core" del profilo durante la personalizzazione, quindi non è possibile una personalizzazione assoluta della pagina profilo                                                                                                                        & Flessibilità                         & 1        \\ 
\hline
Docente  & Profilo                     & L'inidrizzo email esce dal margine creato per contenere e racchiudere i dati, esteticamente sgradevole                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 1        \\ 
\hline
Docente  & Profilo                     & Colori dominanti giallo e azzurro elettrico, non capiso la scelta del colore blu/verde per inidcare i messaggi (ad esempio: dal profilo acceddo alla voce report e poi alla voce "panoramica valutazione", li compare un messaggi con colori differenti dalla palette"         & Stile                                & 1        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Registrazione               & Il pulsante ''Sign Up'' risulta poco visibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  & Visibilità                           & 2        \\ 
\hline
docente  & risorse                     & i metadati richiesti per la compilazione della risorsa sono difficili da riconoscere                                                                                                                                                                                           & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\hline
docente  & risorse                     & la finestra per scegliere il tipo di risorse da aggiungere presenta un numero elevato di tipi, alcuni troppo specifici e quindi poco utilizzabili dal docente (h5p, database, scorm, ims)                                                                                      & Visibilità, Chiarezza o affordance   & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Poco chiara e funzionale, caotica e priva di indicazioni. Non comprensibile la gerarchia di importanza e la disposizione degli elementi                                                                                                                                        & Chiarezza o affordance, Navigazione  & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb non rispecchiano il percorso reale svolto, ma viene aggiunto un passaggio "corsi" quando si clicca su una categoria; inoltre quando si clicca su un corso (es. Algoritmi e strutture dati) vengono aggiunti troppi passaggi "inventati"                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni non sono gerarchizzati visivamente, sono tutti graficamente uguali oppure in due colori (azzurro e giallo) senza che questi colori abbiano un significato funzionale                                                                                                 & Stile                                & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & la breadcrumb nella barra gialla è completamente illeggibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Visibilità                           & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni option e setting page hanno la stessa funzione, ma cambiano nome in diverse pagine                                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Manca spesso un modo facile per tornare alla pagina precedente                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Nella barr gialla il percorso di navigazione a volte è erratto e non sempre le voci sono linkate                                                                                                                                                                               & Navigazione, Controllo               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Spesso macano delle indicazioni, delle spiegazioni su come uno si deve approcciare al sistema, come deve comportarsi e che azioni intraprendere                                                                                                                                & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb presentano delle voci tagliate per mancanza di spazio                                                                                                                                                                                                            & Navigazione                          & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & 20px circa inutili di una barra gialla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Link, indirizzi ecc non funzionanti nel footer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Tutte                       & Il logo nel footer non è linkato/premibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & Navigazione                          & 1        \\ 
\hline
admin    & Tutte                       & ci sono molti elementi che, pur avendo la stessa funzione (campi form, dropdown, bottoni, link...) differiscono nello stile in diverse sezioni e pagine della piattaforma                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\hline
Admin    & Tutte                       & mancanza di feedback se l operazione è andata a buon fine o meno dopo aver cliccato su aggiungi un blocco                                                                                                                                                                      & Feedback                             & 2        \\ 
\hline
Tutti    & Voci di menù                & Non si capisce la voce/pagina attiva, non viene scurita o sottolineata la pagina nella quale ci si trova                                                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! First thing you need to get rid of the `\begin{table}...` environment. That will create a floating object, and it will *never* split through pages. Then change the tabular to longtable, and adjust the details looking at the manual. (Next time, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct, the package, as well as the environment, is called `longtable`. It provides many options for repeating head rows, foot rows, a caption etc. (see the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)). For instance, I added `\endhead` in the example to repeat the same head row, each time the table continues on a new page.

Because your table is too wide to fit the standard layout, you would need to reduce column widths. The other solution, if you want to keep the table unchanged, is to reduce margins on each page spanned by the table (using `geometry`) but be wary the latter approach starts a new page every time you change the layout; that is usually not a problem with long tables.

As a suggestion, I also removed all horizontal and vertical lines, with the exception of a header, and stretched the table so it would be easier to distinguish each row. The latter is controlled by `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}`. Any factor greater than 1.0, here `1.75`, will stretch a table, vertically.

A screenshot showing the first two pages

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy texts

\begin{document}

\kant[1][1]

\newgeometry{margin=1in}
\begingroup
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
    \centering
    \begin{longtable}{p{1.4cm}p{1.9cm}p{7.8cm}p{2cm}p{1.2cm}}
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col 3} & \textbf{Col 4} & \textbf{5} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    Ruolo & Luogo del problema (pagina) & Descrizione del problema & Euristiche violate & Gravità \\ 
    Studente & Amministr. del corso & lo studente in options, altro, metodi di iscrizione, può vedere quanti utenti si sono iscritti e in quale modo. & Vincoli & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Amministr. del corso & lo studente in options, altro, iscrizioni, può vedere l'elenco dei partecipanti al corso, ma iscrizioni è fuorviante perchè sembra indicare che lo studente può iscrivere altre persone & Convivialità & 1 \\ 
    docente & Amministr. del corso & nella sezione della reportistica sono presenti un numero eccessivo di voci e di pagine possibili e non è chiara la differenza fra ogni singola pagina; quando vi si accede non ci sono indicazioni di come interagire, né sono presenti dati & Navigazione, Stile & 3 \\ 
    docente & Amministr. del corso & la visualizzazione dei filtri è confusa e non si sa quali dati ci si può aspettare di trovare; i filtri sono mal organizzati & Chiarezza o affordance & 3 \\ 
    docente & Amministr. del corso & nella sezione di overview statistics non è presente ne la legenda per leggere i grafici ne l'indicazione dei dati su ascisse e ordinate; non si può interagire con i grafici & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3 \\ 
    docente & Amministr. del corso & spesso i filtri sono graficamente diversi fra le diverse pagine della reportistica & Coerenza, Stile & 2 \\ 
    admin & Amministr. sito & la reportistica è scritta in modo troppo tecnico e risulta incomprensibile per l'utente (es.:"The user with id '2' viewed the course with id '89'.") & Convivialità & 3 \\ 
    admin & Amministr. sito & in un corso, l'elenco degli studenti ha un filtro con 54 tasti, il funzionamento di questo filtro è controintuitivo & Chiarezza o affordance, Flessibilità & 2 \\ 
    Admin & Calendario & Le CTA non sono visibili a causa del contrasto con il colore dello sfondo & Stile & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Categorie & Le dimensioni dei quadrati/rettangoli presentanti i corsi hanno forme e disposizioni differenti senza un apparente motivo & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & cliccando su page settings appare soltanto l'opzione "quadri delle competenze", non si capisce a cosa faccia riferimento questa funzione & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & le Categorie non aiutano ad orientarsi all'interno di whoteach, sono poco significative (es. il corso di digitalizzazione 4.0 è dentro alla categoria sviluppo personale mentre potrebbe tranquillamente rientrare nella categoria abilità informatiche) & Navigazione & 3 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & Premendo sulla voce menù "categorie" la schermata rimane quasi uguale alla home, non si capisce se l'operazione richiesta è andata a buon fine & Navigazione & 3 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & pur senza aver fatto login, è possibile navigare le Categorie e vedere chi sono le aziende clienti di whoteach & Vincoli & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & in una categoria, le cards delle sottocategorie e dei corsi sono troppo simili e non separati in modo chiaro & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & l'informazione sulla data di quando una categoria è stata modificata l'ultima volta non è significativa & Visibilità & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Categorie & come studente è possibile vedere corsi a cui non posso accedere, ne posso fare richiesta di accedere & Vincoli & 2 \\ 
    Admin & Gestione corsi & la riordinazione dei corsi èoco comprensibile, buono l'uso delle icone, ma non chiaro lo scopo per il quale è necessario selezionare le voci & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Home & in home (pagina delle Categorie) non c'è un modo semplice per cercare un corso, bisogna navigare all'interno di ogni categoria; si riesce ad accedere facilmente ad un corso solo se si ha il link & Navigazione & 3 \\ 
    Studente & Menù navigazione & a differenza degli altri "pallini" del menu, che aprono un submenu a fumetto, l'icona dei messaggi apre una sidebar a cassetto & Coerenza & 2 \\ 
    Docente & Preferenze & Icona dell'occhio per scurire lo sfondo visibile e disponibile solo in alcune pagine non in tutte & Familiarità & 1 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & riguarda alla timeline sui dati non è ben comprensibile la sua funzione, probabilmente una scelta stilistica, ma non ne sono sicuro (io la associo ad altre funzioni) & Familiarità & 3 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & Non capisco il senso di permettere ad uno studente di poter modificare il layout della pagina profilo & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & Per un profilo studente, nella pagina del profilo ci sono informazioni inutili (privacy e politiche, sessioni, primo e ultimo accesso al sito, possibilità di accedere ad app tramite qr code senza che esista l'app) & Familiarità, Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & nella pagina dle profilo i colori delle bulletlist sono diversi fra di loro (gialli e rossi) senza che ci sia una spiegazione del perchè & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & nella pagina del profilo non è chiaro cosa il tasto modifica permetta di modificare, perchè sembra che sia per i campi sotto ma se si preme se ne possono modificare anche altri & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & la voce profilo moodlenet nei dettagli del profilo non è spiegato cosa sia, non si sa dove reperire informazioni, non è utile per lo studente standard & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 2 \\ 
    Studente & Profilo & Non è possibile spostare il "core" del profilo durante la personalizzazione, quindi non è possibile una personalizzazione assoluta della pagina profilo & Flessibilità & 1 \\ 
    Docente & Profilo & L'inidrizzo email esce dal margine creato per contenere e racchiudere i dati, esteticamente sgradevole & Stile & 1 \\ 
    Docente & Profilo & Colori dominanti giallo e azzurro elettrico, non capiso la scelta del colore blu/verde per inidcare i messaggi (ad esempio: dal profilo acceddo alla voce report e poi alla voce "panoramica valutazione", li compare un messaggi con colori differenti dalla palette" & Stile & 1 \\ 
    Tutti & Registrazione & Il pulsante ''Sign Up'' risulta poco visibile & Visibilità & 2 \\ 
    docente & risorse & i metadati richiesti per la compilazione della risorsa sono difficili da riconoscere & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3 \\ 
    docente & risorse & la finestra per scegliere il tipo di risorse da aggiungere presenta un numero elevato di tipi, alcuni troppo specifici e quindi poco utilizzabili dal docente (h5p, database, scorm, ims) & Visibilità, Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Poco chiara e funzionale, caotica e priva di indicazioni. Non comprensibile la gerarchia di importanza e la disposizione degli elementi & Chiarezza o affordance, Navigazione & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & le breadcrumb non rispecchiano il percorso reale svolto, ma viene aggiunto un passaggio "corsi" quando si clicca su una categoria; inoltre quando si clicca su un corso (es. Algoritmi e strutture dati) vengono aggiunti troppi passaggi "inventati" & Chiarezza o affordance & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & i bottoni non sono gerarchizzati visivamente, sono tutti graficamente uguali oppure in due colori (azzurro e giallo) senza che questi colori abbiano un significato funzionale & Stile & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & la breadcrumb nella barra gialla è completamente illeggibile & Visibilità & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & i bottoni option e setting page hanno la stessa funzione, ma cambiano nome in diverse pagine & Chiarezza o affordance & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Manca spesso un modo facile per tornare alla pagina precedente & Navigazione & 3 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Nella barr gialla il percorso di navigazione a volte è erratto e non sempre le voci sono linkate & Navigazione, Controllo & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Spesso macano delle indicazioni, delle spiegazioni su come uno si deve approcciare al sistema, come deve comportarsi e che azioni intraprendere & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & le breadcrumb presentano delle voci tagliate per mancanza di spazio & Navigazione & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & 20px circa inutili di una barra gialla & Stile & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Link, indirizzi ecc non funzionanti nel footer & Navigazione & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Tutte & Il logo nel footer non è linkato/premibile & Navigazione & 1 \\ 
    admin & Tutte & ci sono molti elementi che, pur avendo la stessa funzione (campi form, dropdown, bottoni, link...) differiscono nello stile in diverse sezioni e pagine della piattaforma & Stile & 2 \\ 
    Admin & Tutte & mancanza di feedback se l operazione è andata a buon fine o meno dopo aver cliccato su aggiungi un blocco & Feedback & 2 \\ 
    Tutti & Voci di menù & Non si capisce la voce/pagina attiva, non viene scurita o sottolineata la pagina nella quale ci si trova & Chiarezza o affordance & 2 \\
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup

\restoregeometry

\kant[2][1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

- Long tables should not be incapsulated in floating environment.
- For them have been developed many package, from the (oldest) `longtable` to the (newest) `tabularray`.
- The main difference between them are in suported colun types and combinations of other packages as are `threeparttable` etc.

In your case I would use the `tabularray` package because of simple and short code and nice result. For better spacing of text in cells I  would reecoment `\small` font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My long table},
  label = {tab:???}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c X[0.16,c] X[0.68, j] X[0.16,c] c},
                  colsep  = 3pt,
                  rows    = {font=\small},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
Ruolo    
    & Luogo del problema %(pagina) 
        & Descrizione del problema    
            & Euristiche violate 
                & Gravità               \\
% table body
Studente 
    & Amministr. del corso   & lo studente in options, altro, metodi di iscrizione, può vedere quanti utenti si sono iscritti e in quale modo.
            & Vincoli               & 2 \\
Studente 
    & Amministr. del corso  & lo studente in options, altro, iscrizioni, può vedere l'elenco dei partecipanti al corso, ma iscrizioni è fuorviante perchè sembra indicare che lo studente può iscrivere altre persone                                                                                        
        & Convivialità              & 1 \\
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione della reportistica sono presenti un numero eccessivo di voci e di pagine possibili e non è chiara la differenza fra ogni singola pagina; quando vi si accede non ci sono indicazioni di come interagire, né sono presenti dati                                   & Navigazione, Stile                   & 3        \\
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & la visualizzazione dei filtri è confusa e non si sa quali dati ci si può aspettare di trovare; i filtri sono mal organizzati                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\

docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione di overview statistics non è presente ne la legenda per leggere i grafici ne l'indicazione dei dati su ascisse e ordinate; non si può interagire con i grafici                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\

docente  & Amministr. del corso        & spesso i filtri sono graficamente diversi fra le diverse pagine della reportistica                                                                                                                                                                                             & Coerenza, Stile                      & 2        \\

admin    & Amministr. sito             & la reportistica è scritta in modo troppo tecnico e risulta incomprensibile per l'utente (es.:"The user with id '2' viewed the course with id '89'.")                                                                                                                           & Convivialità                         & 3        \\

admin    & Amministr. sito             & in un corso, l'elenco degli studenti ha un filtro con 54 tasti, il funzionamento di questo filtro è controintuitivo                                                                                                                                                            & Chiarezza o affordance, Flessibilità & 2        \\

Admin    & Calendario                  & Le CTA non sono visibili a causa del contrasto con il colore dello sfondo                                                                                                                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\

Tutti    & Categorie                   & Le dimensioni dei quadrati/rettangoli presentanti i corsi hanno forme e disposizioni differenti senza un apparente motivo                                                                                                                                                      & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & cliccando su page settings appare soltanto l'opzione "quadri delle competenze", non si capisce a cosa faccia riferimento questa funzione                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & le Categorie non aiutano ad orientarsi all'interno di whoteach, sono poco significative (es. il corso di digitalizzazione 4.0 è dentro alla categoria sviluppo personale mentre potrebbe tranquillamente rientrare nella categoria abilità informatiche)                       & Navigazione                          & 3        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & Premendo sulla voce menù "categorie" la schermata rimane quasi uguale alla home, non si capisce se l'operazione richiesta è andata a buon fine                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & pur senza aver fatto login, è possibile navigare le Categorie e vedere chi sono le aziende clienti di whoteach                                                                                                                                                                 & Vincoli                              & 2        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & in una categoria, le cards delle sottocategorie e dei corsi sono troppo simili e non separati in modo chiaro                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & l'informazione sulla data di quando una categoria è stata modificata l'ultima volta non è significativa                                                                                                                                                                        & Visibilità                           & 2        \\

Studente & Categorie                   & come studente è possibile vedere corsi a cui non posso accedere, ne posso fare richiesta di accedere                                                                                                                                                                           & Vincoli                              & 2        \\

Admin    & Gestione corsi              & la riordinazione dei corsi èoco comprensibile, buono l'uso delle icone, ma non chiaro lo scopo per il quale è necessario selezionare le voci                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Home                        & in home (pagina delle Categorie) non c'è un modo semplice per cercare un corso, bisogna navigare all'interno di ogni categoria; si riesce ad accedere facilmente ad un corso solo se si ha il link                                                                             & Navigazione                          & 3        \\

Studente & Menù navigazione            & a differenza degli altri "pallini" del menu, che aprono un submenu a fumetto, l'icona dei messaggi apre una sidebar a cassetto                                                                                                                                                 & Coerenza                             & 2        \\

Docente  & Preferenze                  & Icona dell'occhio per scurire lo sfondo visibile e disponibile solo in alcune pagine non in tutte                                                                                                                                                                              & Familiarità                          & 1        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & riguarda alla timeline sui dati non è ben comprensibile la sua funzione, probabilmente una scelta stilistica, ma non ne sono sicuro (io la associo ad altre funzioni)                                                                                                          & Familiarità                          & 3        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & Non capisco il senso di permettere ad uno studente di poter modificare il layout della pagina profilo                                                                                                                                                                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & Per un profilo studente, nella pagina del profilo ci sono informazioni inutili (privacy e politiche, sessioni, primo e ultimo accesso al sito, possibilità di accedere ad app tramite qr code senza che esista l'app)                                                          & Familiarità, Chiarezza o affordance  & 2        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina dle profilo i colori delle bulletlist sono diversi fra di loro (gialli e rossi) senza che ci sia una spiegazione del perchè                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina del profilo non è chiaro cosa il tasto modifica permetta di modificare, perchè sembra che sia per i campi sotto ma se si preme se ne possono modificare anche altri                                                                                               & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & la voce profilo moodlenet nei dettagli del profilo non è spiegato cosa sia, non si sa dove reperire informazioni, non è utile per lo studente standard                                                                                                                         & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 2        \\

Studente & Profilo                     & Non è possibile spostare il "core" del profilo durante la personalizzazione, quindi non è possibile una personalizzazione assoluta della pagina profilo                                                                                                                        & Flessibilità                         & 1        \\

Docente  & Profilo                     & L'inidrizzo email esce dal margine creato per contenere e racchiudere i dati, esteticamente sgradevole                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 1        \\

Docente  & Profilo                     & Colori dominanti giallo e azzurro elettrico, non capiso la scelta del colore blu/verde per inidcare i messaggi (ad esempio: dal profilo acceddo alla voce report e poi alla voce "panoramica valutazione", li compare un messaggi con colori differenti dalla palette"         & Stile                                & 1        \\

Tutti    & Registrazione               & Il pulsante ''Sign Up'' risulta poco visibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  & Visibilità                           & 2        \\

docente  & risorse                     & i metadati richiesti per la compilazione della risorsa sono difficili da riconoscere                                                                                                                                                                                           & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\

docente  & risorse                     & la finestra per scegliere il tipo di risorse da aggiungere presenta un numero elevato di tipi, alcuni troppo specifici e quindi poco utilizzabili dal docente (h5p, database, scorm, ims)                                                                                      & Visibilità, Chiarezza o affordance   & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Poco chiara e funzionale, caotica e priva di indicazioni. Non comprensibile la gerarchia di importanza e la disposizione degli elementi                                                                                                                                        & Chiarezza o affordance, Navigazione  & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb non rispecchiano il percorso reale svolto, ma viene aggiunto un passaggio "corsi" quando si clicca su una categoria; inoltre quando si clicca su un corso (es. Algoritmi e strutture dati) vengono aggiunti troppi passaggi "inventati"                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni non sono gerarchizzati visivamente, sono tutti graficamente uguali oppure in due colori (azzurro e giallo) senza che questi colori abbiano un significato funzionale                                                                                                 & Stile                                & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & la breadcrumb nella barra gialla è completamente illeggibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Visibilità                           & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni option e setting page hanno la stessa funzione, ma cambiano nome in diverse pagine                                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Manca spesso un modo facile per tornare alla pagina precedente                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Nella barr gialla il percorso di navigazione a volte è erratto e non sempre le voci sono linkate                                                                                                                                                                               & Navigazione, Controllo               & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Spesso macano delle indicazioni, delle spiegazioni su come uno si deve approcciare al sistema, come deve comportarsi e che azioni intraprendere                                                                                                                                & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb presentano delle voci tagliate per mancanza di spazio                                                                                                                                                                                                            & Navigazione                          & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & 20px circa inutili di una barra gialla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Link, indirizzi ecc non funzionanti nel footer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 2        \\

Tutti    & Tutte                       & Il logo nel footer non è linkato/premibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & Navigazione                          & 1        \\

admin    & Tutte                       & ci sono molti elementi che, pur avendo la stessa funzione (campi form, dropdown, bottoni, link...) differiscono nello stile in diverse sezioni e pagine della piattaforma                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\

Admin    & Tutte                       & mancanza di feedback se l operazione è andata a buon fine o meno dopo aver cliccato su aggiungi un blocco                                                                                                                                                                      & Feedback                             & 2        \\

Tutti    & Voci di menù                & Non si capisce la voce/pagina attiva, non viene scurita o sottolineata la pagina nella quale ci si trova                                                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in "profesional" table design cells are not in "jail of vertical and horsontal lines. So you may consider the following MWE and table preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My long table},
  label = {tab:???}
                ]{colspec = {c X[0.16,c] X[0.68, j] X[0.16,c] c},
                  colsep  = 3pt,
                  rows    = {font=\small},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
    \toprule
Ruolo    
    & Luogo del problema %(pagina) 
        & Descrizione del problema    
            & Euristiche violate 
                & Gravità               \\
    \midrule

% table body

    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would employ the [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular/) package and its `xltabular` environment. I would assign the `X` column type to the third column. I'd further use a ragged-right layout rather than a fully justified layout for all columns that allow automatic line breaking.

I'd also employ the `csquotes` package and its `\enquote` macro rather than `"..."` to quote material, and I'd use `\slash` instead of the `/` symbol, as the former allows line-breaking, whereas `/` does not. Finally, I'd get rid of all vertical rules and use fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules with the help of the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.

The following screenshot shows the first few rows of the table that results from applying the suggested changes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[italian=guillemets]{csquotes} % or: "italian=quotes"
\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

% measure desired widths of columns 2 and 4
\newlength\lenA
\settowidth\lenA{Amministr.}   % col. 2
\newlength\lenB
\settowidth\lenB{Navigazione,} % col. 4

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l P{\lenA} >{\RaggedRight}X P{\lenB} c @{}}

% headers and footers 
\toprule
Ruolo    & Luogo del problema (pagina) & Descrizione del problema                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & Euristiche violate                   & Gravità  \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot


% body of table

studente & Amministr. del corso        & lo studente in options, altro, metodi di iscrizione, può vedere quanti utenti si sono iscritti e in quale modo.                                                                                                                                                                & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Amministr. del corso        & lo studente in options, altro, iscrizioni, può vedere l'elenco dei partecipanti al corso, ma iscrizioni è fuorviante perchè sembra indicare che lo studente può iscrivere altre persone                                                                                        & Convivialità                         & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione della reportistica sono presenti un numero eccessivo di voci e di pagine possibili e non è chiara la differenza fra ogni singola pagina; quando vi si accede non ci sono indicazioni di come interagire, né sono presenti dati                                   & Navigazione, Stile                   & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & la visualizzazione dei filtri è confusa e non si sa quali dati ci si può aspettare di trovare; i filtri sono mal organizzati                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & nella sezione di overview statistics non è presente ne la legenda per leggere i grafici ne l'indicazione dei dati su ascisse e ordinate; non si può interagire con i grafici                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & Amministr. del corso        & spesso i filtri sono graficamente diversi fra le diverse pagine della reportistica                                                                                                                                                                                             & Coerenza, Stile                      & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Amministr. sito             & la reportistica è scritta in modo troppo tecnico e risulta incomprensibile per l'utente (es.: \enquote{The user with id `2' viewed the course with id `89'.})                                                                                                                           & Convivialità                         & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Amministr. sito             & in un corso, l'elenco degli studenti ha un filtro con 54 tasti, il funzionamento di questo filtro è controintuitivo                                                                                                                                                            & Chiarezza o affordance, Flessibilità & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Calendario                  & Le CTA non sono visibili a causa del contrasto con il colore dello sfondo                                                                                                                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Categorie                   & Le dimensioni dei quadrati\slash rettangoli presentanti i corsi hanno forme e disposizioni differenti senza un apparente motivo                                                                                                                                                      & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & cliccando su page settings appare soltanto l'opzione \enquote{quadri delle competenze}, non si capisce a cosa faccia riferimento questa funzione                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & le Categorie non aiutano ad orientarsi all'interno di whoteach, sono poco significative (es. il corso di digitalizzazione 4.0 è dentro alla categoria sviluppo personale mentre potrebbe tranquillamente rientrare nella categoria abilità informatiche)                       & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & Premendo sulla voce menù \enquote{categorie} la schermata rimane quasi uguale alla home, non si capisce se l'operazione richiesta è andata a buon fine                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & pur senza aver fatto login, è possibile navigare le Categorie e vedere chi sono le aziende clienti di whoteach                                                                                                                                                                 & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & in una categoria, le cards delle sottocategorie e dei corsi sono troppo simili e non separati in modo chiaro                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & l'informazione sulla data di quando una categoria è stata modificata l'ultima volta non è significativa                                                                                                                                                                        & Visibilità                           & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Categorie                   & come studente è possibile vedere corsi a cui non posso accedere, ne posso fare richiesta di accedere                                                                                                                                                                           & Vincoli                              & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Gestione corsi              & la riordinazione dei corsi èoco comprensibile, buono l'uso delle icone, ma non chiaro lo scopo per il quale è necessario selezionare le voci                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Home                        & in home (pagina delle Categorie) non c'è un modo semplice per cercare un corso, bisogna navigare all'interno di ogni categoria; si riesce ad accedere facilmente ad un corso solo se si ha il link                                                                             & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Menù navigazione            & a differenza degli altri \enquote{pallini} del menu, che aprono un submenu a fumetto, l'icona dei messaggi apre una sidebar a cassetto                                                                                                                                                 & Coerenza                             & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
Docente  & Preferenze                  & Icona dell'occhio per scurire lo sfondo visibile e disponibile solo in alcune pagine non in tutte                                                                                                                                                                              & Familiarità                          & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & riguarda alla timeline sui dati non è ben comprensibile la sua funzione, probabilmente una scelta stilistica, ma non ne sono sicuro (io la associo ad altre funzioni)                                                                                                          & Familiarità                          & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & Non capisco il senso di permettere ad uno studente di poter modificare il layout della pagina profilo                                                                                                                                                                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & Per un profilo studente, nella pagina del profilo ci sono informazioni inutili (privacy e politiche, sessioni, primo e ultimo accesso al sito, possibilità di accedere ad app tramite qr code senza che esista l'app)                                                          & Familiarità, Chiarezza o affordance  & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina dle profilo i colori delle bulletlist sono diversi fra di loro (gialli e rossi) senza che ci sia una spiegazione del perchè                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & nella pagina del profilo non è chiaro cosa il tasto modifica permetta di modificare, perchè sembra che sia per i campi sotto ma se si preme se ne possono modificare anche altri                                                                                               & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & la voce profilo moodlenet nei dettagli del profilo non è spiegato cosa sia, non si sa dove reperire informazioni, non è utile per lo studente standard                                                                                                                         & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
studente & Profilo                     & Non è possibile spostare il \enquote{core} del profilo durante la personalizzazione, quindi non è possibile una personalizzazione assoluta della pagina profilo                                                                                                                        & Flessibilità                         & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
Docente  & Profilo                     & L'inidrizzo email esce dal margine creato per contenere e racchiudere i dati, esteticamente sgradevole                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
Docente  & Profilo                     & Colori dominanti giallo e azzurro elettrico, non capiso la scelta del colore blu\slash verde per inidcare i messaggi (ad esempio: dal profilo acceddo alla voce report e poi alla voce \enquote{panoramica valutazione}, li compare un messaggi con colori differenti dalla palett         & Stile                                & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Registrazione               & Il pulsante \enquote{Sign Up} risulta poco visibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  & Visibilità                           & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & risorse                     & i metadati richiesti per la compilazione della risorsa sono difficili da riconoscere                                                                                                                                                                                           & Chiarezza o affordance, Convivialità & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
docente  & risorse                     & la finestra per scegliere il tipo di risorse da aggiungere presenta un numero elevato di tipi, alcuni troppo specifici e quindi poco utilizzabili dal docente (h5p, database, scorm, ims)                                                                                      & Visibilità, Chiarezza o affordance   & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Poco chiara e funzionale, caotica e priva di indicazioni. Non comprensibile la gerarchia di importanza e la disposizione degli elementi                                                                                                                                        & Chiarezza o affordance, Navigazione  & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb non rispecchiano il percorso reale svolto, ma viene aggiunto un passaggio \enquote{corsi} quando si clicca su una categoria; inoltre quando si clicca su un corso (es. Algoritmi e strutture dati) vengono aggiunti troppi passaggi \enquote{inventati}                          & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni non sono gerarchizzati visivamente, sono tutti graficamente uguali oppure in due colori (azzurro e giallo) senza che questi colori abbiano un significato funzionale                                                                                                 & Stile                                & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & la breadcrumb nella barra gialla è completamente illeggibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Visibilità                           & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & i bottoni option e setting page hanno la stessa funzione, ma cambiano nome in diverse pagine                                                                                                                                                                                   & Chiarezza o affordance               & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Manca spesso un modo facile per tornare alla pagina precedente                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 3        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Nella barr gialla il percorso di navigazione a volte è erratto e non sempre le voci sono linkate                                                                                                                                                                               & Navigazione, Controllo               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Spesso macano delle indicazioni, delle spiegazioni su come uno si deve approcciare al sistema, come deve comportarsi e che azioni intraprendere                                                                                                                                & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & le breadcrumb presentano delle voci tagliate per mancanza di spazio                                                                                                                                                                                                            & Navigazione                          & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & 20px circa inutili di una barra gialla                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Link, indirizzi ecc non funzionanti nel footer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 & Navigazione                          & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Tutte                       & Il logo nel footer non è linkato\slash premibile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & Navigazione                          & 1        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Tutte                       & ci sono molti elementi che, pur avendo la stessa funzione (campi form, dropdown, bottoni, link\dots) differiscono nello stile in diverse sezioni e pagine della piattaforma                                                                                                      & Stile                                & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
admin    & Tutte                       & mancanza di feedback se l operazione è andata a buon fine o meno dopo aver cliccato su aggiungi un blocco                                                                                                                                                                      & Feedback                             & 2        \\ 
\addlinespace %% \hline
tutti    & Voci di menù                & Non si capisce la voce\slash pagina attiva, non viene scurita o sottolineata la pagina nella quale ci si trova                                                                                                                                                                       & Chiarezza o affordance               & 2        \\

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```